# Как в батнике получить ссылку на каталог расположения этого батника?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, powershell

Я оперирую относительными путями в BAT файле. И я должен запускать его как

> cmd /k somepath\mybatfile.bat

и таким образом текущий каталог и `%CD%` переменная это `windir`. Мне надо как-то перейти в каталог где физически лежит батник. Можно ли в батнике получить ссылку на каталог расположения этого батника?

Answer (score 0):

Решено через переменную `%0`.

```
%~d0
cd %~p0
```